# Why the guests aren't entering my ride?

Tags: planet-coaster

Well, every time I change my ride operations conf, I see the queue people walk a little, like a stuttering move. But they aren't entering my ride and are complaining about queue time and it took like 20 min. What I'm missing? Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is likely about a bug that was fixed years ago.

Comment: @Philipp I'm not sure if that is a good reason to close this.  It may be old, but if we could dig up patch notes or some other proof that this was a resolved bug, that could be an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think it will be the positioning of the ride in the park. If there is a higher prestige ride nearby, or shops (and people are thirsty) then the queue is not worth it.

In the RCT days the spacing between rides and shops would affect an easy win or not. I am going to stick my neck out and say that AI got better.

Comment: People don't back out of a queue once in it except if the ride breaks or you stop it from operating. In OP's screenshot, people are already in the queue.

Comment: I haven't said anything about people leaving the queue. Not at all sure where you got that from!?

Comment: The evaluation of ride prestige and shop/need fulfillment happens before entering a queue, not after. Once in a queue, people WILL go on the ride, barring breakdowns or manual shutdowns.